# ¿Cómo modificar la clase de un <div> si el cliente es un teléfono móvil?

Tags: javascript, html5

He intentado diferentes soluciones de internet pero ninguna ha funcionado, o por lo menos correctamente.
Lo último que probé fue:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function changeClass() { 
  window.mobileCheck = function() {
    let check = false;
    (function(a){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))) check = true;})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
    return check;
  }; 
  let output = window.mobileCheck;
  if (output)
  {
 
document.getElementById('nameForClassThatChangeIfMobileDevice').className = "github-component d-flex flex-column flex-justify-between windtext-left {% if site.style == 'dark' %}box-shadow{% else %}border border-gray-light{% endif %} bg-white rounded-1 p-3";  
 }
}
```

Y no funcionó.

Alguien me podría decir que funciones de JavaScript o que etiquetas de HTML5 debo usar para que una función detecte al cargar la página si el cliente es un teléfono móvil, y en el caso en el que lo sea que la clase de un "div" se modifique con otro contenido.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Inserté un script tag con una función que buscaba el div según el id, y cambiaba la clase si un bool de una función que hice que usaba el agent para comprobar si pertenecía a un móvil. Pero no funcionó, hice algo similar pero sin el agent, usaba una lista con nombre de teléfonos y usé una propiedad que encontré en Internet para obtener el buscador, pero cambiaba sólo una clase y no sólo en móvil.

Answer (score 0):

Tu solución no funciona porque estás haciendo esto:

```
let output = window.mobileCheck;
```

Dentro de `mobileCheck` hay una función y para ejecutarla y obtener su valor debes colocar los paréntesis:

```
let output = window.mobileCheck();
```

Modifiqué la comprobación del userAgent de la  función mobileCheck por una más compacta.

```js
function changeClass() {
  window.mobileCheck = function () {
    return /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(
      navigator.userAgent
    );
  };

  let isMobile = window.mobileCheck();

  if (!isMobile) {
    // esto se va a ejecutar si no es movil
    document.getElementById("div").className = "clase";
  }
}

changeClass();
```

```css
.clase{

background-color : red;

}
```

```html
<div id="div" >

Se agrega la clase en dispositivos que no son móviles

</div>
```